# Error in profiler for Matlab 2014a

Tags: matlab, profiler

I use osx mavericks with 2014a. To get a crisp screen I have updated the JRE and done the fix to the help-menu as described in the answer from 17 May here http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102946-why-does-the-matlab-desktop-look-blurry-when-using-matlab-8-2-r2013b-on-my-mac-with-retina-display

This includes following the instructions from Mathworks http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/870843

Maybe that is the reason for the error below but it is not certain as I had never tried the profiler on 2014a before I did the fix.

***The Error:***

When I try to click any function to get a detailed profiler report I get the following error:

Error using flip
  Too many input arguments.

Error in flipud (line 14)
  x = flip(x,1);

Error in profview>makefilepage (line 723)
  sortedDataList = flipud(sortedDataList);

Error in profview (line 70)
      s = makefilepage(profileInfo,idx, busyLineSortKeyStr2Num(busyLineSortKey));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have your own function called `flip` on your MATLAB path? There is a new function shipping with MATLAB called `flip` which the profiler is trying to use.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flip.html

Try `which -all flip` - if you have a version on there, try removing it to see if that fixes things.

Comment: That was it. Such a basic thing.. Thanks